# Camel multicast pipeline timing out in a transacted doTry

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, atomikos

I'm running into a very odd problem that happens only under very specific circumstances.
I have the following route

```
<routes id="id1" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route id="id2">
    <from uri="{{input}}"/>
    <log message="Started route"/>

    <transacted/>

    <doTry>
        <multicast>
            <pipeline>
                <log message="Started 1" />
                <log message="Finished 1" />
            </pipeline>

            <pipeline>
                <log message="Started 2" />
                <log message="Finished 2" />
            </pipeline>
        </multicast>

        <log message="Finished multi"/>

        <doCatch>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <log message="Exception happened"/>
        </doCatch>
    </doTry>
</route>
</routes>
```

This prints the following

```
Started route
Started 1
Finished 1
Started 2
Finished 2
```

It then hangs until you terminate the process. `Finished multi` is never logged. After 10 seconds I get a message from Atomikos (the transaction manager) that looks like

```
Transaction tm168555531112800002 has timed out and will rollback.
```

When I terminate the process, camel tells me there's 1 inflight exchange for route `id2`. Graceful shutdown fails after 10 seconds and it has to kill the main thread.

```
The following threads are blocked and will be interrupted so the threads are released
Blocked Thread --- Id: 1 Name: main RouteId: id2 NodeId: multicast1
```

Now here's the fun part. Changing the route in any of these ways fixes the problem and everything works as expected:

- Removing one of the log messages from the second pipeline. Doesn't matter what you put in the first one, the second pipeline must contain only a single line.
- Removing one pipeline block completely
- Making the multicast concurrent with `parallelProcessing = true`
- Removing `<transacted/>`
- Moving the multicast outside `<doTry>`

I'm using Camel 3.15.0 with Spring Boot 2.6.4

Comment: Did you already try to put the pipelines in 2 separate sub-routes (so that you have a simple multicast to "direct:subroute1" and "direct:subroute2" ? I'm curious to see if it makes some differences

Comment: @TacheDeChoco I just tried and it made no difference - both subroutes logged their two respective messages but the multicast still hangs. I tried with and without pipeline wrapping the <to uri="..."/> elements.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to one or more threads being blocked, so the transaction cannot proceed to commit and times out.

Try a thread dump to see the details, that should show more details to work with. Maybe there is a race condition on a shared connection pool or something.